# Conversion of double to string gives exponent values

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a string `32,646,513.32` to a double and then convert it to a string in scientific notation like this `3.264651332E7`. The code below is

```
double amount = 0;

        for (Payments payments : pvor.getPayments()) {
            payments.setDocumentNumber(pvor);
            amount += Double.parseDouble(payments.getAmount());
            payments.setDate(new Date());

        }

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        double totalAMount = Double.valueOf(df.format(amount));
        Double totalAMounts = (Double) totalAMount;
        pvor.setAmount(String.valueOf(totalAMounts.doubleValue()));
```

How do I display large numbers in same format as I give?

Comment: May I ask the end goal? Why are you converting it to double in the first place?

Comment: its from datatable and i need to add the amount for total but the bean value is a string ,

Comment: `Double.toString(totalAMount)` should return a `String` in non scientific form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly then you do not need `String.valueOf()` but `String.format()`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String input = "32,646,513.32";
    double value = Double.parseDouble(input.replace(",",""));
    String output = String.format("%f",value);
    System.out.println("Value: " + output);
}
```

Output:

```
Value: 32646513.320000
```

Replace the following line in your code appropriately:

```
/* Note the change from `valueOf()` to `format()` */ 
pvor.setAmount(String.format("%f",totalAMounts.doubleValue()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using just `String.valueOf(totalAmounts)`, which give you number in exponential format, you need to format your double value to match the string format that you want. Try something like `new DecimalFormat("#,###.00").format(totalAmounts)`. Or simply use `String.format("%,.2f", totalAMounts)`.